# Debian 8 touchscreen in console mode is this possible?

Tags: debian, touch-screen

I have a PoS Terminal running Debian 8. Do I have to load X server to allow the touchscreen to work?

My application is designed for a touch interface, and if possible I would like to load the application from the text console (mainly so the system has a much ram as it can so the program runs fast).

The application displays its own mouse icon when the program loads (this is displayed even if no mouse drivers are install as it is part of the graphical support of the programming language I use).

Would I set up and install the screen in full GUI mode and then boot into the console mode and start the program?

On my keyboard-based systems this works perfectly, but I am not 100% sure if this is possible with the touchscreen. I have seen machines boot right into the PoS applications, but this is on an IBM 4690 operating system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, touch screen input is implemented in hardware as a serial port that sends data when you touch the screen.  In Linux this is usually intercepted by the `inputattach` program and the data is converted to emulate a traditional mouse which can be read from `/dev/input/mice` or similar.

Check out the ever-helpful archlinux pages on [serial input](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/serial_input_device_to_kernel_input) and [console mouse](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Console_mouse_support).